# Separate promotion site

Tags: php, drupal, web, kohana

I'm building a project in PHP, using the Kohana framework. It will eventually have support for multiple users, so a login screen, etc. I also have some kind of "promotion site", which will probably tell how good the product is, and have help pages and a FAQ, etc.

My question is: what are the (dis)advantages of having my project and the promotion site as separate sites, for example the promotion site using something like Drupal in a separate directory? The alternative is building the pages as a part of my project, using Kohana. How well does having two separate frameworks work (Drupal and Kohana), in probably different directories in the same hosting? (I like the idea of having all of Drupal's stuff for doing the content of the help pages, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the drupal stuff is in a different folder, then really it should not affect kohana at all. Seperate folders act as well, separate folders. You could also put it on a subdomain like help.example.com. Whatever you like, should not be a problem. I use a wordpress blog with my main site being Kohana.

Answer (score 0):

Having separate sites for content/custom development will probably end up more work in the long run. Every time you update the theme on Drupal, you'll need to update it on your Kohana project too. In addition, maybe in the future you will need more integration - for example you may want certain pages to be visible only by users who are logged in.

For situations like this I usually develop an extremely basic CMS for the content part of the site. It's not too big a task - make a 'CMS' module so you can reuse your code in other projects. Create a 'pages' table and model to store the pages. Use TinyMCE or similar for the page editing interface.

In the CMS module's init.php, you can create a loop which goes through all the pages and creates routes for them (these would be checked before the default <controller>/<action> route)

```
<?php
$pages = Model::factory('page')->find_all();
foreach($pages as $page){
    Route::set('page_'.$page->id, $page->uri)
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display'));
}
```

If you're only going to be editing the content pages yourself, you could skip the whole page edit interface and just edit the raw html in the database. Not quite as elegant as Drupal, but you'll  have much tighter integration and you'll save yourself the bloat that comes with Drupal.

Comment: Why so many routes? You can just try to catch them all (with last route) and then in controller check if the page exist. If it does - show it, if not - show 404 page.

Comment: True, but this way pages can have any url - for example you might want nested pages such as "products/toys/baby/super-toy-2000".
I guess you could do the same with regex, but wouldn't that add overhead to each page load?